# Passing a dataframe to Pandas LinearRegression model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

I'm creating a LinearRegression model using Pandas. After fitting the model I can predict a value for single test data row using the model. When I try to pass a dataframe **to predict multiple values** (with relevant columns only) it gives the error '`method' object is not subscriptable`. Since I'm new to pandas library can anyone give me a help on this? Here is the sample code (run in jupyter notebook).

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
Output: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)

y_predicted = model.predict([[-0.0189,-0.0189,0.1027286,0.0912,78.6,298.492857143,298.55,294.527142857,301.1,296.4,25.37,78.7814285714,78.6,15.9185714286,3.12857142857,26.5285714286,7.05714285714,33.3,21.7,75.2]])
y_predicted
Output: array([ 6.04893094]) # OK

x_test = pd.read_csv('test_set.csv')
y_predicted = model.predict[x_test] # ??? Error Here

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-c5e16b55c3a9> in <module>()
----> 1 y_predicted = model.predict[x_predict]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `model.predict` is a function.  Try `model.predict(...)`, like in the fourth line of your code.  Note the `()` and not `[]`.

Comment: Use round brackets to pass arg in method `y_predicted = model.predict(x_test)`